# Terraform output for eip allocation id

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have a simple terraform code to create eip.This works fine.

```
resource "aws_eip" "envoy" {
  count = length(var.subnet_cidr_public)
  vpc   = true
    tags  = "${merge(map("Name","envoyadmin-${count.index}"),var.tags)}"
}

output "envoy_eip" {
  description = "Elastic ip address for Envoy nlb services"
  value       = aws_eip.envoy.*.allocation_id
}
```

The problem I have is with the terraform output.Eventhough the eips are created in AWS account, the allocation_ids are shown as null in terraform output. What could be the issue with this and how to fix it?

```
terraform output
envoy_eip = [
  null,
  null,
  null,
]
```

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear how you can do that?

Answer (score 5):

The `allocation_id` is actually now provided through `id` as explained in the github [issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/6640). Thus, you should have:

```
output "envoy_eip" {
  description = "Elastic ip address for Envoy nlb services"
  value       = aws_eip.envoy.*.id
}
```

Also this is only `id`, not "Elastic ip address" as you wrote in description. For public IP you need to use:

```
output "envoy_eip" {
  description = "Elastic ip address for Envoy nlb services"
  value       = aws_eip.envoy.*.public_ip
}
```